# google cloud Stackdriver Metrics to scale an Manage instance group - Regional

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud, autoscaling, gce-instance-group

What are the Stackdriver Metrics we can use to autoscale Regional Manage instance groups ? When i check the docs it says Regional managed instance groups do not support filtering for per-instance metrics. Regional managed instance groups do not support autoscaling using per-group metrics.

Is that mean I can not use any Stackdriver Metrics other than CPU ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/scaling-stackdriver-monitoring-metrics#limitations), you're right by saying that Regional Manage Instance Group have some limitations:

- You cannot autoscale based on Cloud Monitoring logs-based metrics.
- Regional managed instance groups do not support filtering for per-instance metrics.
- Regional managed instance groups do not support autoscaling using per-group metrics.

However, you can still using the autoscaler capability by using the standard form:

- [Scaling based on CPU utilization](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/scaling-cpu)
- [Scaling based on load balancing serving capacity](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/scaling-load-balancing)

Comment: we are having some tcp LB as well and can not use LB base in some application as well